# Why does using rename in a called subroutine not work?

Tags: file, batch-file, rename

The code snippet below fails at the rename command:

```batch-file
@echo

for %%i in ("C:\Users\vzwk6\Downloads\test\*.*") do (
    set fnam=%%~ni
    set ext=%%~xi
    REM To set the modified date
    set MDate=%%~ti
    set ParsedDate=!MDate:~6,4!-!MDate:~0,2!-!MDate:~3,2!
) & call :checker
goto :eof

:checker
::Checks if file already has date prefixed
if "%fnam:~4,1%"=="-" (call :found) else (call :notfound)
goto :eof

:notfound
REM Do the rename adding Modified date
ren "!fnam!!ext!" "!ParsedDate! !!fnam!!ext!"
goto :eof

:found
goto :eof
```

In the `:notfound` subroutine, the rename is failing with message:
`The system cannot find the file specified`

I tried using `%%i` with escape chars and double quotes, then switched to use existing line.
Still not working for me.

Anyone have a workable solution?

My goal: do renames of files in a directory adding prefix date formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD filename.ext` and I want to bypass files that already have the prefix formatted date

Example of directory to modify:

```
2021-02-28 file1.txt  
file2.txt              <== has modified date of 3/5/2022  
file3.txt              <== has modified date of 3/6/2022
```

Should be changed to look like (using modified date of each file):

```
2021-02-28 file1.txt  
2022-03-05 file2.txt  
2022-03-06 file3.txt
```

Comment: First things first you certainly have what appears to be a typo: `"!ParsedDate! !!fnam!!ext!"` should surely read as `"!ParsedDate! !fnam!!ext!"`. Next I would assume that you should be `call`ing `:checker` before you close the `do` command. Otherwise it will only work with the last file assigned to `%%i`.

Answer (score 1):

Final code that works.  Thanks all for your comments and suggestions.

```
@echo
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%i in ("C:\Users\vzwk6\Downloads\test\*.*") do (
    set fnam=%%~ni
    set ext=%%~xi
    REM To set modified date
    set MDate=%%~ti
    set ParsedDate=!MDate:~6,4!-!MDate:~0,2!-!MDate:~3,2!
    
    REM Do the rename adding Modified date
    if not "!fnam:~4,1!"=="-" (
        ren "%%i" "!ParsedDate! !fnam!!ext!"
    )
)

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see is that the ren command is outside the for loop, so it will only be executed once (after all files has been processed). To fix this, the ren command should be inside the for loop. Something like this.

```
for %%i in ("C:\Users\vzwk6\Downloads\test\*.*") do (
    set fnam=%%~ni
    set ext=%%~xi
    REM To set modified date
    set MDate=%%~ti
    set ParsedDate=!MDate:~6,4!-!MDate:~0,2!-!MDate:~3,2!
    
    REM Do the rename adding Modified date
    if not "%fnam:~4,1%"=="-" (
        ren "!fnam!!ext!" "!ParsedDate! !!fnam!!ext!"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ren` command will attempt to rename the file in the **CURRENT** directory, whereas the filename is acquired from the **TARGET** directory `C:\Users\vzwk6\Downloads\test`.

```
set "targetdir=C:\Users\vzwk6\Downloads\test"
for %%i in ("%targetdir%\*.*") do (
```

then

```
ren "%targetdir%\"%fnam%%ext%" "%ParsedDate% %fnam%%ext%"
```

Note that `!var!` is not required as (eg) `fnam` is not being changed in the `:notfound` routine which contains no code blocks (parenthesised sequence of commands) - same way as you have use `%fnam%` within `:checker`

And @Michaelc is correct - the `call :checker` should be inside the `for` loop, for the reason stated.